# MySQL and LINQ to SQL via Connector/Net | C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-sql, connector-net

I need to get data from MySQL database using Connector/Net and Linq2SQL.

Is it possible to do without DBlinq or smth else?

Found this example - http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article100.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, LINQ to SQL only supports the MS SQL database.**

DbLinq uses the Connect/Net ADO driver but I wouldn't recommend DbLinq for any serious production use. We found the implementation to be buggy and it was a CPU hog on even the simplest queries (plus it appeared to have issues using connection pooling correctly).

We switched to DevArt's [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/), which has been much more stable with less "gotchas" from a coding perspective (it's basically a drop-in replacement for LINQ to SQL) but it's a commercial product which has a license fee. It's cheaper than alternatives such as LightSpeed and LLBLGen though. Plus depending on your schema, their free version can be used if you only need to access 10 entities per database.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm not working with something serious, simple study task.

Comment: FWIW, Linq to SQL can be a big CPU hog on MSSQL as well.  Doesn't provide an answer, just wanted to point out the CPU hogginess of the LinqToSQL approach isn't confined to that provider ... :)